Does the linear regression fit follow the inverse relationship?
I fitted a X =logA, Y=logB with a weighted linear regression and I got the result as log B  =(0.53 $\pm$ 0.054)logA + (17.41 $\pm$ 1.7). When I did the fit with X=logB, Y=logA, I expect the relationship to be something like logA ~ 2logB. But I got the result as logA=(1.15 $\pm$ 0.06)logA - (8.32 $\pm$ 2.038). Why the inverse relationship is not seen here? Any explanations for that?

Please search our site for regression X Y.  Including [faq] in the search can help narrow it.
